# useState doesnt inititalize on fetched data on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

when this component is loaded , fetch function should fetch the data and store the data in the store using reducer . When i use useSelector to select that data and initialize that value using useState , it is not getting updated in the first render . i want the data to be fetched and stored using useState. kindly help me to store the fetched data using useState in the state variable so that the fetched data is initialized at first render .

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchQA } from '../../store/actions/qp';
import ListQA from '../../components/ListQA';

const QAScreen = props =>{
    subjectId = props.route.params.subjectId;

   const dispatch = useDispatch()



       // fetching the data using dispatch

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchQA(subjectId))
    },[dispatch]);

    const selectedQuestions = useSelector(state => state.qa.questionAndAnswers);

    **const [userTestDetails,setUserTestDetails] = useState(selectedQuestions);**



    return(<View>
        <Text> welcome to QA Screen</Text>
        <FlatList   **data={userTestDetails}** // not updating on initial render
                    keyExtractor={item=>item.questionId}
                    renderItem={itemData => <ListQA data={itemData.item} index={itemData.index} />}
        />
    </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I am not getting why you are putting `selectedQuestions` in local state. And are you getting values in `selectedQuestions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store the data obtained from redux into state, you can directly use that value unless you want to do some local manipulations

```
const QAScreen = props =>{
    subjectId = props.route.params.subjectId;

   const dispatch = useDispatch()



       // fetching the data using dispatch

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchQA(subjectId))
    },[dispatch]);

    const userTestDetails = useSelector(state => state.qa.questionAndAnswers);





    return(<View>
        <Text> welcome to QA Screen</Text>
        <FlatList   data={userTestDetails}
                    keyExtractor={item=>item.questionId}
                    renderItem={itemData => <ListQA data={itemData.item} index={itemData.index} />}
        />
    </View>
    )
}
```

Also since you are dispatching an action that fetches and updates the data in reducer, it is correct that you won't have the data immediately, if at all you wish to update the state, you need to make use of `useEffect`

```
const QAScreen = props =>{
    subjectId = props.route.params.subjectId;

   const dispatch = useDispatch()



       // fetching the data using dispatch

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchQA(subjectId))
    },[dispatch]);

    const selectedQuestions = useSelector(state => state.qa.questionAndAnswers);
    const [userTestDetails,setUserTestDetails] = useState(selectedQuestions);
    useEffect(() => {
          setUserTestDetails(userTestDetails);
    }, [selectedQuestions]);



    ...
}
```